# Publisher data not found for Ads in @capacitor-community/admob

Tags: android, admob, capacitor, interstitial, capacitor-plugin

I am using [capacitor-community/admob](https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob) in my Ionic 5 and Capacitor 3 project. I have completed all the setup as per documentation and test interstitial and rewardedVideo ads are working fine with the test ads ids provided [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#demo_ad_units).

I have set up my Admob account correctly and created Ad units before a couple of days. So, It's not new. There are no warning or error messages or issues with the account. Double checked the app id and ad unit ids in my app. App id is maintained in android string.xml as

```
<string name="admob_app_id">ca-app-pub-***</string>
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml as

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />
```

I have linked my Admob with the Firebase account. So the file `google-services.json` also contains the ads App id.

The Ads are working when using test ids but not loading when using real Ads. Following is the error I am getting.

```
Publisher data not found. <https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9905175#9>
```

I have checked all the information under Publisher data not found but it's not helping.

Comment: what does impression count says in admob console?

Comment: @AmodGokhale - Total impressions is 0 along with requests and Match rate count

Comment: if your test ids are showing correctly, give it some time for real ids to work ( it might takes days before it is activated ).  Make sure app is live on play store and its linked in admob console to your app ID

Comment: Thank you! One thing is missing here. My app is not live yet. It's in Alpha testing. According to https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10037806?hl=en I need to add the App store details in my Ads app. So, Can't I see the ads until the app is live?

Comment: Yes, you need to link it. You should not use live advertisements in testing ( might be ban ). Implement a switch to continue using test ad and move to real one once app is live. If your test advertisements are looking good, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks!! If you can put this as answer I can it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important links to get correct advertisements

1. Check for setup issue, policy issue https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9469204?hl=en
2. Link your app to admob account https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10037806?hl=en
3. Run Admob troubleshooter https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685

Once app is made live, give it some time before live advertisements start showing. Don't use live ads during testing

Visit admob policy implementation guidelines https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en